# How to display routes to and from a location using Google Maps in Android Studio

Tags: java, google-maps

So I am trying to create a route planner that has google maps but I want to have google maps working in android studio and allow the user to input their source location and their destination location and click display track and it will show the user the routes to them any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate Google Maps into your Android Studio project and display the route between two locations using the Google Maps Directions API. You'll need to obtain an API key from the Google Cloud Console and include it in your project.

You can then make HTTP requests to the API to retrieve the route information and display it on the map.

To find the API documentation and tutorials on how to integrate Google Maps into Android Studio at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start.

Comment: I'm using Java and Android Studio how can I do it in that? @TalMalka

Comment: You should check out the client library for Java https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java